# what videos can play in windows mobile pocket pc

Tags: video, windows-mobile

I am using an old windows mobile 6.5 device. I would like to know what videos can be played through a web browser embedded in my native application?

I am talking about Pocket IE.  Spent ages searching and cannot find an answer.

Thanks

Comment: Windows Mobile came with a stripped down version of IE4. I have not found any videos that will play through the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PIE can play video/audio if you have the right COM objects in place. The WMP (windows media player) can be embeded into PIE html or directly into your native app.

See also [Using the Windows Media Player Control in a web page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564581%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Sample page](http://israeliteidentity.com/wm_sample.html) holds something like this:

```
   <OBJECT ID="PlayerOCX" WIDTH=160 HEIGHT=192 classid="CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95"
standby="Loading Microsoft Windows Media Player components..." type="application/x-oleobject">
    <PARAM NAME="Filename" VALUE="\My Documents\wm_sample.wmv">
<PARAM NAME="Volume" VALUE="-600">
<PARAM NAME="Autostart" VALUE="1">
<PARAM NAME="PlayCount" VALUE="1">
<PARAM NAME="showStatus" VALUE="1">
```

More with a search of "pocket internet explorer embed wmp"

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. I will try this very soon and get back to you. I had noticed however, that when i use an embedded web browser control in my mobile app that if I point the URL to an mp4 file on my server it will play it. It prompts me to save or open this file first though.  It does not look like it is playing in Windows Media.  I have Opera installed (if it helps). What process is playing this mp4 file? Would you know?  Thanks

Comment: If you speak about PocketIE or IEM you can go on with WMP embedding. Opera Mobile will not embedd ActiveX objects like the WMP one! I assume you may embed a flash player inside opera mobile. But I am not sure. You may look for alterantive Media Player ActiveX for PocketPC like http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer_pocketpc/downloads/player.html

Comment: Hi, that was not what i meant at all.  I now all about ActiveX controls and how to use them. What I said is that when I set the URL of the Web Browser to an MP4 file I have on the server it plays.  Something on my device is associating with that file but it did not look like wmp.  So, I was wondering wether Opera 'took' over the process of running the MP4 file.  The adobe link looks good.  Let me have a look at that one. Thanks

Comment: I am not sure I will use either of these optins on the basis of outside influences but you have given me enough info to do this if i need to do.  So.. you deserver a green tick :).  BTW i did take a look at DirectShow.NETCF which looked promising. I looked at this example but could not get it to work... http://alexmogurenko.com/blog/programming/windows-mobile-how-to-play-audiovideo-c-or-directshownet-cf-part-i/

Comment: The application associated with a mime type is determined by the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT (HKCR) registry entries. For example you will see a .wmv entry that leads to MWVFile and the associated application.